# Serverless bug when setting up jwt authorizer: Error: Serverless Offline only supports retrieving JWT from the headers (undefined)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless

I followed the documentation word for word from here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#jwt-authorizers

Once I run everything, I get the following error:

> Error: Serverless Offline only supports retrieving JWT from the headers (undefined)

This is my code:

```
provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    stage: dev
    apiGateway:
        binaryMediaTypes:
            - 'multipart/form-data'
    httpApi:
        authorizers:
            someJwtAuthorizer:
                type: jwt
                identitySource: $request.header.Authorization
                issuerUrl: https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<user_pool_id>
                audience:
                    - <app client id>
...

functions:
    animals:
        handler: lambdas/animals.animalsHandler
        events:
            - httpApi:
                  path: /api/animals
                  method: get
                  authorizer:
                      name: someJwtAuthorizer
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs here: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline

> For HTTP APIs, JWT authorizers defined in the serverless.yml can be used to validate the token and scopes in the token. However at this time, the signature of the JWT is not validated with the defined issuer. Since this is a security risk, this feature is only enabled with the --ignoreJWTSignature flag. Make sure to only set this flag for local development work.